# send SMS from website

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have google around and try to see if I could find something php server where you can see it on to mobile etc.. I have read me until that one must have an API code before you can do it.

Hope you can help me

Feel free to ask me if there's anything else you want to know?

i have to try its here:

```
// Create a Clockwork object using your API key
$clockwork = new Clockwork( $key );

// Setup and send a message
$message = array( "to" => "441234567890", "message" => "Hello World" );
$result = $clockwork->send( $message );

// Check if the send was successful
if( $result["success"] ) {
    echo "Message sent - ID: " . $result["id"];
} else {
    echo "Message failed - Error: " . $result["error_message"];
}
```

I can in no way get it to work at all. it does not send any SMS. and is download from here:
http://www.clockworksms.com/

I have no api and I do not go out and make money for it. it is such that I come from *Denmark*,.

EIDT! :

```
function sms_server()
    {
        $number = $_POST["mobil"];
        $tekst = $_POST["tekst"];
        $clockwork = new Clockwork("785c853......");

        $message = array( "to" => $number, "message" => $tekst);
        $result = $clockwork->send( $message );

        if( $result["success"] ) {
            echo "Message sent - ID: " . $result["id"];
        } else {
            echo "Message failed - Error: " . $result["error_message"];
        }
    }


<form action="#" method="post">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>nummer</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="mobil"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tekst</td>
                    <td><textarea name="sms" style="width:100%;"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send sms"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["send"]))
        {
            $sms_server = $mebe->sms_server();
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Just to check - you have a valid Clockwork key and the `Clockwork` class exists, right?

Comment: do you get any output at all? Any of the `Message sent` or `failed` messages? Please show us what you have tried so far beyond the copying of code, because Stackoverflow is not meant to be a website where you can let others create your code. Additionally your current question does not include a concrete question, we are unaware of what issues you are running against except for "it does not work", which seriously is way too vague.

Comment: Have you signed up for an API key - it seems that having an API key is a must for use of this!

Comment: you can show my code her: http://jsfiddle.net/KH3Mk/

error: Fatal error: Class 'Clockwork' not found in /home/jesperbo/public_html/blabla.dk/indhold/inc/asg.php on line 4592

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you signed up for an API key - it seems that having an API key is a must for use of this! (https://app5.clockworksms.com/signup). You will need to assign the API key they give you to your `$key` variable. Also if you're from Denmark, I'm really not sure that this will work for you as UK mobile numbers are used as examples in their documentation, although I am not sure(?). Actually possibly it'll be fine if you prefix your mobile number with the danish country code

Comment: what should I do when I've got API?

Comment: You should write something like this: `$key = "your API key";` before the rest of the code

Comment: Yes if you want to do it that way that's also fine but storing the API key in the `$key` variable means that you can reuse it at a later date if needed

Answer (score 0):

replace $tekst = $_POST["tekst"];

with this code

$tekst = $_POST["sms"];

and create account with clockwock to get AP-KEY